# Draw labels and buttons programmatically onto a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iPhone app in which I should create a new view based upon some data... so how can I programmatically create a new view with buttons, labels and pictures dynamically? Has somebody an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read

1. [***Create UIButton Programmatically***](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/Create-UIButton-Programmatically.html)
2. [***Creating programmatically a label (UILabel)***](http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/05/08/creating-programmatically-a-label-uilabel/)

And Create then in the View. Here is a very good [***tutorial***](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-creating-basic-buttons) on how to do that !

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

First rightclick on your Xcode project (in ios 5) and select "New file">select cocoa touch>objective c class>subclass of uiview>and name your file name. THen add the following code in the .m file.

```
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programatically, without using a nib.

-(void)loadView {

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeig ht|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
self.view = view;
[view release];

}
```

Then create the buttons as described in below posts.